# Removed unwanted characters from string using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2.5cm','2.5cm','2.56”','1.38”','2.2”','0.8 in','$18.00','4','2"']})
```

which looks like:

```
  A
2.5cm
2.5cm
2.56”
1.38”
2.2”
0.8 in
$18.00
4
2"
```

I want to remove all characters except for the decimal points.

The output should be:

```
 A
2.5
2.5
2.56
1.38
2.2
0.8
18.00
4
2
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
df['A'] = df.A.str.replace(r"[a-zA-Z]", '')
df['A'] = df.A.str.replace('\W', '')
```

but this is stripping out everything including the decimal point.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What about following your way: `df.A.str.replace(r"[^\d.]", "")`: removing any non-digits except for the dot?

Comment: The `^` in the regex negates what's inside; so if it's not a digit nor a literal dot, we remove it. https://regex101.com/r/eIYEin/1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.extract` to extract only the floating points:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+|\d)').astype('float')
```

However, `'.'` here matches any character, not just the period. So it will match `18,00` instead of `18`. Also it fails to extract multidigit whole numbers. Use the code below. (thanks @DYZ):

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+)').astype('float')
```

Output:

```
       A
0   2.50
1   2.50
2   2.56
3   1.38
4   2.20
5   0.80
6  18.00
7   4.00
8   2.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `str.extract`

```
df['new'] = df.A.str.extract('(\d*\.\d+|\d+)').astype(float).iloc[:,0]
Out[31]: 
       0
0   2.50
1   2.50
2   2.56
3   1.38
4   2.20
5   0.80
6  18.00
```

Comment: Or `'(\d*\.\d+|\d+\.?)'` to match numbers like 34. (with a period but no fractional part).